# Debugging DirectX on VS2013 - Drawing Call not appearing, But Vertex Shader is executed

Tags: debugging, directx, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to start working on DirectX 11, but I have so far been unable to draw a single polygon.

I started with sample codes from *[Beginning DirectX 11 Game Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1435458958)* (Chapter 2, simple, untextured triangle) and [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef) from Microsoft's Dev Center.

So far I have created my Device, Context, Swap Chain, Viewport, Vertex and Pixel Shaders, Input Layout and Vertex Buffer for this effect. However, nothing is displayed on screen.

Using [VS2013's Graphics Debugging tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh315751.aspx), I managed to find that my geometry is being sent to the Vertex Shader, apparently in the correct position (Single Triangle in the middle of the screen). However, when I switch to the Graphics Pixel History tool, it appears my drawing call is never executed; Yet, the Graphics Event list says it was.

My vertices are in CW order, no blending/alpha has been enabled, the same debugging tools let me know what all the objects listed above were properly created. Yet nothing appears. Does anybody have a pointer in the right direction?

Comment: +1 for using graphics debugger, which is so rare on StackOverfow =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without shader code and vertex data we can only guess.

And my guess (which is a frequent mistake) is that fragments not passing depth tests due to incorrect Z or W values output in VS (due to incorrect vertex data, incorrect matrices in constant buffers, incorrect calculations, etc.) or incorrect depth buffer settings.

To debug it try this algo:

- Run graphics debugger and capture frame (Print Screen)
- In "Graphics Event List" choose draw function call (with brush near it)
- Click on a pixel in a captured frame (preferably one that belongs to your geometry)
- Look at "Graphics Pipeline Stages" to see if IA, VS, PS and OM stages functional for that pixel
- Check "Pixel history" (unfold all lines). Does anything happens after cleaning buffer? Does your fragments pass depth test? Does you geometry has wrong color?
- On "Graphics Pipeline Stages" or "Pixel history" click green arrow near shader stages to debug their HLSL code. Go line-by-line, watch variables. Check that shaders output valid data to next stages.
- Repeat same for some other pixels of your frame if needed.
- Target is to find on which stage of pipeline things go wrong.

If you cannot find some windows, check menu "Debug" - "Graphics".

Hope it helps.
Happy debugging!

Comment: Turns out the W was the issue there. Was sending 0s when they had to be 1s. Thank you :)